# Why frame of VC's view init from xib not the size of MainScreen?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, frame, xib

I have both Storyboard and XIB VCs. Just experience this:

When initialize VC from XIB, its view's size is {600, 600}, but if initialize from Storyboard, its view's size is same as `UIScreen.main().bounds`.

To dig it deeper, it seems when initialized from storyboard, the view got the property `view.window != nil`, while if initialized from XIB, its `window == nil`. Maybe it's the reason for the strange size.

My question is: Why, and how do I get VC's view from xib got the correct size of MainScreen?

I tried to set manually like this: `vc.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds`, and it works. However, this will also trigger `viewDidLoad` where I do some setup for my contents, and the IBOutlet at the time hasn't loaded and every setup is wrong!

So, a bonus question is raised: How do I force load the IBOutlet after initialized from XIB?

Some sample code which cause this question:

```
import MFSideMenu

...
// initialize from somewhere else and push it to menu.containerVC.centerVC
let vc = MyVC.init(nibName:MyVC.className, bundle:self.nibBundle)
...

// This method is from subclass of MFSideMenuVC
func pushCenterVC(vc: UIViewController!) {

    // This cause the setup in vc.viewDidLoad go wrong
    // If side menu is load for the first time, it doesn't have its window yet.
    if self.view.window != nil {
        vc.view.frame = self.view.window.bounds
    }

    self.menuContainerViewController.centerViewController = vc

    // If I put it here, MFSideMenu will create an ugly shadow because of wrong initilize frame size.
    // if self.view.window != nil {
    //     vc.view.frame = self.view.window.bounds
    // }
}
```

Comment: You probably set your xib file to use size classes. Size classes are 600x600 even from storyboard

Comment: @YunusErenGüzel well yeah, my app is suppose to support multiple devices, so how else should we do it without the help of AutoLayout and SizeClass?

Comment: You can't change it. This is how it should suppose to work. Why is this a problem for you?

Comment: Because I'm trying to migrate new framework into an old project, which is using outdated lib. With your answer like this, I'm going to give up now...

Comment: "However, this will also trigger viewDidLoad" Then you're doing it too soon.

Comment: @matt look at the code, there's a comment about when `viewDidLoad` got called. How should I correct it if as you say, it's too soon?

Comment: Your code is very poorly presented; it doesn't tell me where `if self.view.window != nil` is being called in your overall code. So how on earth am I supposed to know how to "correct" it? You have not revealed what you are doing.

Comment: @matt I've added more code, is it okay now?

Comment: Yes, thanks! But it doesn't change what I said. You've got an initialized view controller `vc` with no view. You then say `vc.view`, causing the view controller to load its view. That triggers `viewDidLoad`. That is all totally expected. If you don't want that to happen, don't do that. To put it another way, it is meaningless to try to set the frame of a view controller's view at a time when it does not yet even _have_ a view; that's what I mean by "too early".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My question is: Why, and how do I get VC's view from xib got the correct size of MainScreen?**

You are expecting right size when sizing code didn't run yet. After
    func viewDidLayoutSubviews() ran, view will have correct size. Using size of the view before that is just asking for trouble and you are relying on undefined behavior that can change with new iOS release.

**How do I force load the IBOutlet after initialized from XIB?**

Easily, just access view in init() method of your view controller. For example ask for size of the view, view will be loaded.

Comment: but why when init vc's view from storyboard got the correct size? plus, can you be more specific in your 2nd answer (ask for the size of the view)? isn't it `let rect = vc.view.frame`?

Comment: This is so called "undefined behavior". Apple may choose to implement default state as they like, because they didn't do any promises. It is bad idea to rely on it. it might change again with new version of Xcode. Your example is correct.